# How can I change the line width of all selected lines to the same value in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I have drawn a vector graphic with Inkscape that consists of only bezier curves. I scaled some of those lines so their width got changed. Now I would like to have all lines be the same width.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Select the lines you want.
2. Then go to the *Fill and Stroke* dock:

   [image]
3. Change to *px* (or any other unit other than %) and input the value you want.

   [image]